# Delete items synchronously angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resources, synchronization

I have to delete items in a for loop the moment I close a bootstrap modal.
Currently I am setting a delay of 3 secs on the modal close, so that the delete can happen within those 3secs in the background but this is not very efficient.
What is the best way to ensure that the modal closes only when all the items are deleted successfully? Perhaps by making the delete synchronous ? Or promises?

```
$scope.idList = [1, 2, 3];
$scope.deleteItems = function(deleteList){
    angular.forEach( deleteList, function(item) {
        DeleteAPI.remove({itemId: item}, {}, $scope.delSuccess, $scope.delError);
    });
}
$scope.close = function(){
    var pmodal = $modal.open( {
            templateUrl: 'route/pmodal.html',
            controller: 'DeleteCtrl'
        } );
        pmodal.result.then(
            function(check) {}, 
            function(check) {
                if ( check=='proceed' ) {
                    $scope.deleteItems( $scope.idList );
                    $timeout( function() {
                        $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
                    }, 3000);
                }
            },
            function(check) {}
        );

}
```

Comment: `What is the best way` Please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is requesting our opinion and there is a variety of possible solutions (as you said, AJAX, Promises). Either rephrase your question, or find which you want to use, do some research about it and try to code it. If you have a problem with the way you chose after that, then you can come and ask (after searching for the solution by yourself and debugging).

Comment: The Async library works pretty well for situations like this. You can use Async.each, which will run each of your deletes, but will not continue on until they are all done. I have not used it in the browser before, but it works well in node.js. Don't know if it's too heavy a library for your app or not, but it does say it works in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $q.all or you can simple count responses as Javascript is not multithread:

```
pmodal.result.then(
var success = 0;
var failed = 0;
var check = function() {
   if (success + failed == deleteList.length) {
      if (failed != 0) {
          // do smth?
      } else {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
      }
   }
}
angular.forEach( deleteList, function(item) {
    DeleteAPI.remove({itemId: item}, {}, function() {
        success++;
        check();
    }, function() {
        failed++;
        check();
    });
});
```